# Understanding min_tag_id and max_tag_id

Tags: real-time, instagram, endpoint

**tag_media_recent** takes as max_id and min_id as parameters.
The documentation says :
**MIN_ID**  Return media before this min_id.
**MAX_ID**  Return media after this max_id.

I tried `max_id = 3390883111979` (very large than what is currently used)
It returns the newest tagged images. Doesn't it follow the definition of min_id? seems erraneous

I also tried `min_id = 1390922265529` and `max_id = 1390922265528`. It returns 12 images. How is that possible when the max range given is 3?

I also tried reversing the values used in `min_id` and `max_id`. Still 16 images.....

**Could not make out anything from min_tag_id and max_tag_id...**

Anybody got any answer ??

Comment: I have run into the same problems and figured most of them, are you using a specific API, it would be easier to answer in that context (otherwise the answer can be long)

Comment: Just the API-console given by Instagram. It would be of great help if you could clear things up.

Comment: I am facing a similar dilemma - here is my question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729166/instagram-search-for-a-tag-within-particular-date-range  let me know if you figured out anything for this one

Answer (score 6):

I think you are asking generally how min_tag_id and max_tag_id work. (I know this question is stale but hopefully this helps someone)

So it is confusing the way Instagram has labeled these:

**MIN_ID Return media before this min_id.**
**MAX_ID Return media after this max_id.**

The definitions of "**before**" and "**after**" are from the perspective of *pages of media*, in which the first page is newest media and the last page is oldest.

Instagram named things with the next query in mind, I guess. So if you query for recent media and the response has a "min_tag_id" of 1234, that is actually the high id mark in the response (what you would hope would be named 'max_tag_id'). That min_tag_id is what you would use to get *newer* media, next time you query. Likewise, the max_tag_id is what you would want to search *up to*, if you want to page through to *older* media.

For instance, you may notice that '**next_url**' in the response is simply another query with 'max_tag_id' parameter set to that response's max_tag_id. http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/

Hope that adds some clarity.