# Pathetic state of Instagram API

Tags: instagram-api

Related questions with answers which are no more valid:

- [How Does Instagram's GET/tags//media/recent Pagination Actually Work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625173/how-does-instagrams-get-tags-tag-media-recent-pagination-actually-work)
- [Understanding min_tag_id and max_tag_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399865/understanding-min-tag-id-and-max-tag-id)
- [Instagram Search for a tag within particular date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729166/instagram-search-for-a-tag-within-particular-date-range)

As I am exploring the Instagram API and my app is in sandbox mode, I am surprised by API at every step. This should not be condition of public API
( who cares !).

The Api end point I am trying to is:

[https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent)

Well the required parameters are:

- access_token     [A valid access token.]
- max_tag_id   [Return media after this max_tag_id.]
- min_tag_id   [Return media before this min_tag_id.]
- count    [Count of tagged media to return.]

Since I dont know how to get or generate `max_tag_id` and `min_tag_id`, I skipped and tried this :
 `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/jokes/media/recent?access_token=x.y.x&count=10`

The response I get is:

> {"pagination": {"deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are
>   deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"},
>   "data": [], "meta": {"code": 200}}

May be I need `max_tag_id` and `min_tag_id` and lets trying putting 
rang values 1 to 10 ( I dont know how to generate these values )

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/jokes/media/recent?access_token=x.y.x&count=10&min_tag_id=1&max_tag_id=10`

The response I get is:

> {"meta": {"code": 400, "error_type": "APIInvalidParametersError",
>   "error_message": "max_id must not be a media id."}}

Now the error is misleading, I never provided parameter `max_id` as you can see.

Please help to reduce this insanity

For those who are not getting the question:

- What is the valid value for `max_tag_id` and `min_tag_id`
- What is the meaning of `max_id must not be a media id.` when there is no such parameter passed etc ..

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to be more explicit about what the problem is.

Comment: I am explicit about API documentation and not getting due information from their documentation alone so , asking for help

Comment: What exactly is the question here? We can't change the API any more than you can.

Comment: @JJJ, please check edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are in Sandbox mode, so you will not get any public data, you will only get data from you or your sandbox users. 
Try search for an hashtag that you have posted a photo for, then you will just see that photo in API response.
Once you get approved with `public_content` permission, and go live, you will see all data.

`max_tag_id` and `min_tag_id` are encrypted now, you cannot just generate, you first make a API call without the `max_id` or `min_id`, you will get the response with 20 results with `max_tag_id` in the pagination section of API response, which you can use this `max_tag_id` to make next API call, for next set of 20 results.
(and btw you will have pagination in API response only if you are approved by Instagram and are out of Sandbox, so go figure, good luck)

Comment: Thanks that makes sense